# Counter Examples for Dominated Convergence Theorem and Fatou's Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Is there an example to see why the dominated convergence theorem fails when there is no integrable function dominates the sequence $f_n(x)$?
Also for Fatou's lemma, is there an example where the strict inequality holds?, i.e:
$$\int_X f(x)\text{d}\mu < \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_X f_n(x) \text{d}\mu$$

Answer (score 6):

Let $X$ be the line with Lebesgue measure and let $f_n(x) = \chi_{[n,n+1]}(x)$. This is a counterexample for both questions.

Comment: Thank you Umberto P. Could you please clarify it because I am not familiar with these theorems.

Comment: What do you need clarified?

Comment: For D.C.T. Why $f_n(x)$ is not dominated?? Does the sequence go to infinity?

Comment: And for Fatou what is $f(x)$?

Comment: The sequence $f_n$ converges everywhere to $0$, so $f(x) = 0$. Note that if $f_n(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, then in particular $g(x) \ge 1$ for all $x \in [1,\infty)$ so that $g$ cannot be integrable.

Comment: Aha. Thank you Umberto.

Comment: Sorry Umberto, I have a question, our X is [0,∞] or [−∞,∞]? Waht is the domain and the range of fn(x)?  It looks like the range is {0,1} and the domain is $(-∞,∞)$. Am I right?

Comment: Either $[0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,\infty)$ is an acceptable domain.

Comment: Is this true: the inequality for Fatou will be  $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)dx$ = $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}0=0$ $<$ $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_n(x)dx$$ = $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int \limits_{n}^{n+1}1dx $ $=1$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26969/discussion-between-fabian-and-umberto-p).

Answer (score 2):

To complement Umberto P.'s example, here is another which shows that the inequality in Fatou's lemma can be strict: let $(X,\mu)$ be a probability space, and let $E \subset X$ be a measurable subset of positive (but not full) measure. Define
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
\chi_E(x), & \textrm{ $n$ odd, }\\
\chi_{E^c}(x) = 1-\chi_E(x), & \textrm{ $n$ even}.
\end{cases}
$$
It follows that
$$
\int_X \left(\liminf_{n \to \infty} f_n \right) d\mu = 0 < \min\{ \mu(E), 1-\mu(E) \} = \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_X f_n d\mu.
$$